# ASP.NET Charting Pie Chart - both inside and outside label per slice

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, charts, asp.net-charts

In an existing applications (web forms, but the underlying Microsoft Charting stack is basically the same for winforms/webforms/razor charts) I have Pie Charts, with for each slice the following business data:

1. Value
2. Label
3. Color (used for categorization, same color for multiple slices)

The requirement is a Chart that has all information layout out in one chart like this (mockup):

[image: Pie Chart with both inside and outside Labels]

Using the CustomProperties on the Series/Points I can display each datapoint with either an Inside

[image: Pie Chart with Labels inside]

Or an Outside Label:

[image: Pie Chart with Labels outside]

But not both. Can I somehow trick the Pie Chart into displaying *both* an inside and outside label for each data point?

I realize that this is an edge case (normally you'd use legend+color to visualize this, but we already use color to categorize). I'd rather avoid rendering to a bitmap first and manually rendering the label texts on there (because there are mechanisms in place to stream the charts to both web pages and generated documents).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two series and two chart areas and superimpose them:

[image]

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">
    <series>
        <asp:Series ChartType="Pie" 
            Name="Series1" 
            CustomProperties="PieLabelStyle=Inside, PieStartAngle=270" 
            BorderColor="White" 
            ChartArea="ChartArea1">
        </asp:Series>
        <asp:Series ChartType="Pie" 
            Name="Series2" 
            CustomProperties="PieLabelStyle=Outside, PieStartAngle=270" 
            ChartArea="ChartArea2">
        </asp:Series>
    </series>
    <chartareas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" >
            <InnerPlotPosition Height="95" Width="45.98404" X="27.00798" Y="2.50000072" />
        </asp:ChartArea>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea2" 
            AlignWithChartArea="ChartArea1"
            AlignmentOrientation="All"
            BackColor="Transparent">
            <InnerPlotPosition Height="95" Width="45.98404" X="27.00798" Y="2.50000072" />
        </asp:ChartArea>
        </chartareas>
</asp:Chart>
```

**CS:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<MyDataModel> data = new List<MyDataModel> {
        new MyDataModel { Color = Color.LightBlue, Label = "Value 1", Value = 100 },
        new MyDataModel { Color = Color.LightBlue, Label = "Value 2", Value = 100 },
        new MyDataModel { Color = Color.LightBlue, Label = "Value 3", Value = 100 },
        new MyDataModel { Color = Color.Blue, Label = "Value 4", Value = 100 },
        new MyDataModel { Color = Color.Blue, Label = "Value 5", Value = 400 },
    };

        foreach (MyDataModel dm in data)
        {
            Chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(new DataPoint
            {
                Color = dm.Color,
                Label = dm.Value.ToString(),
                YValues = new double[] { dm.Value }
            });

            Chart1.Series[1].Points.Add(new DataPoint
            {
                Color = Color.Transparent,
                Label = dm.Label,
                YValues = new double[] { dm.Value }
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: I... didn't know you could do that with ChartAreas. Absolutely brilliant, compositing charts like that makes the Charting component a lot more powerful.

Comment: @Paul-Jan : I think it's an ugly hack...:O), but apparently that's all we got for the job at hand.